# onclick handlers gets prefixed with "x-" by WinJS

Tags: angularjs, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

We currently port a cordova app developed with AngularJS from Android / iOS to Windows. Its build as Universal App and gets therefore executed in a WinJS environment.

Now we got the problem that we set a onclick-Attribute dynamically in special cases (where we cant use ng-click) but the attribute gets prefixed with "x-" by the WinJS runtime(at least I think so). Is there a way to supress this behavior?

Best regards and thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am noticing the same behavior.

Comment: @Justin We ended up making ng-click work instead by writing a special bind-html-compile directive that explicitly sets the ng-click attribute and then compiles the HTML block, thus avoiding the need to use onclick.